# Print contains of an array in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to print this array. Following is my code. But its prints some weird characters 9 times(like: ϵϵϵϵϵϵϵϵϵ)... Please tell me what's wrong?

```
.data
    arr db 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

.code
Main Proc

    mov cx, 9
    l1:
    lea si, arr
    mov bl, arr[si]
    mov dl, bl

    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    inc si
    loop l1
```

Comment: Shouldn't these numbers be ASCII-characters? If  so, you need 50, 51, 52, ..., 48.

Comment: You are right but how can i use the actual numbers(2,3,4,5) instead of using ASCII-characters(50,51,52...)? And there is another problem, 'si' is not incrementing. Its printing the same index 9 times...

Comment: @user3520573 just add `0x30h` to any of the digits `0 - 9` for the ASCII equivalent, this works in reverse, subtract `0x30h` from any ASCII digit `'0' - '9'` to get back to the value.

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't use ASCII. It uses a code page like [437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: The lower half of CP437 (where the digit characters are) matches ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the **ASCII-character** you want to display into `dl`. How to put ASCII-chars into your program depends on your assembler, it may be easiest to just calculate the numerical value yourself.
As for the actual code, your loop-label `l1` is in the wrong position, and some of the code around it is redundant. You might write the program like this:

```
.data
    arr db 50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,48

.code
Main Proc

    mov cx, 9
    #wrong position l1:
    lea si, arr
    #redundant mov bl, arr[si]
l1:
    mov dl, [si]
    mov ah, 2   #not sure if this could be moved in front of the loop, check if syscall clobbers ah
    int 21h
    inc si
    loop l1
```